# IOS Push Notifications issues

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app is not receiving any push notiifcaitons, but well send. (ios 11.1.2, Xcode 9.1).

Here my code
Many many thanks,
David

[2017-12-19 00:36:57][info] Send notification for #3090 event.
[2017-12-19 00:36:57][error] Send errors: Error: Not connected to Push Notification Service

0 /var/www/twist/vendor/bryglen/yii2-apns-gcm/Apns.php(194): ApnsPHP_Push->send()

1 /var/www/twist/console/pusher/Sender.php(36): bryglen\apnsgcm\Apns->sendMulti(Array, 'Jean D a aj...', Array, Array)

2 /var/www/twist/console/pusher/EventsNotificator.php(207): console\pusher\Sender->send('Jean D a aj...', Array, Array, Array)

3 /var/www/twist/console/pusher/EventsNotificator.php(101): console\pusher\EventsNotificator->sendEvent(Object(common\models\Event))

4 /var/www/twist/console/controllers/PusherController.php(64): console\pusher\EventsNotificator->process()

5 /var/www/twist/console/controllers/PusherController.php(45): console\controllers\PusherController->process()

6 [internal function]: console\controllers\PusherController->actionRun()

7 /var/www/twist/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)

8 /var/www/twist/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(154): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)

9 /var/www/twist/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(108): yii\base\Controller->runAction('run', Array)

10 /var/www/twist/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(454): yii\console\Controller->runAction('run', Array)

11 /var/www/twist/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(167): yii\base\Module->runAction('pusher/run', Array)

12 /var/www/twist/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(143): yii\console\Application->runAction('pusher/run', Array)

13 /var/www/twist/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))

14 /var/www/twist/yii(24): yii\base\Application->run()

## 15 {main}

Comment: Are you checking whether you get a device token back from Apple and are you passing that to your back-end?

Comment: How do you know it sends correctly?

Comment: @Yitzchak because i see it on the app and on the Back End. On the app i receive the notiifcation on the notification section (ex: someone liked your profile) but i do not receive any push notifications or badge number on the app icone or on the notification icone on the App

Comment: You should post the notification uri so we can check it out

Comment: @Yitzchak could it be because of certificates ?

Comment: Everything is possible.. You can try to integrate **Batch** for push notifications. https://batch.com It takes 10 minutes (create account, pod install, add a few lines of code and send push notification), it's an easy way to test your certificate :)

Comment: @Yitzchak small question: i just renew my certificates. Should I download the new p12 on my backend ?

Comment: The backend that sends the push notification? Sure! The application that send the push request to APNS should have the correct certificate!

Comment: @Yitzchak yes! ok last error i have are :

Comment: @DavidSchz What is the last error?

Comment: @Yitzchak Hello, The error is bellow. Many thanks

Comment: The error is in your backend, it looks like it doesn't connected to APNS, please remove your answer and insert the error as an edit in your question... Check why your backend doesn't connect to APNS